# Is it safe to remove empty directories inside a .git folder?

Tags: git

Every working copy of a git repository has a hidden folder named ".git". I found it may contain empty folders like "feature", "hotfix", "tags" and more.
Is it safe to remove them? Will they be recreated if needed?

Comment: Are you using [`git-gc`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) every now and then? I'd try that first.

Comment: Yes git gc doesn't delete them, even not git gc --aggressive.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Git will recreate any folders if it needs to. Deleting empty folders is totally fine.

That said, I can't see any reasons to delete them. They aren't doing anything to you, are they?

Comment: Oh yes they are threatening my life! Every night I hear their voices. They are after me! It's horrific!
LOL Let's just say I have my reasons. ;-)

Comment: "Villains!" I shrieked, "dissemble no more! I admit the deed! --tear up the filesystem! here, here! --It is the beating of the hideous empty directories!"

Comment: But if something's going to threaten you with a "hotfix", aren't you just a _little_ bit curious?

Answer (score 1):

It's NOT safe. I tried it and now git fsck claims it's not a git repository!

Comment: The minimal valid git repo is `mkdir -p .git/{objects,refs}; echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD; >.git/config`. Your problem isn't removing empty directories.